# Need some guidance with a small calculator I am working on Ruby

Tags: ruby, math

```
def averager
puts "Put in three numbers. One per line"
num_1 = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_i
num_2 = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_i
num_3 = $stdin.gets.chomp.to_i

half_total =  num_1 + num_2 + num_3
total = half_total / 3
end
```

Ok so that is a little averager I am working on. It works fine except for one thing. I would like the user to decide how many numbers he wants to type in. That way I wouldn't be limited to just three numbers to average
. Thanks

Comment: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html and http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Integer.html#method-i-times should help you.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard any advice on how I could integrate that into the code?

Comment: Ask the user how many numbers he wants to enter, use Integer#times to loop and get each number, store them in an array, then sum up like you do at the end of your code. (Alternatively, you could do without the array by just keeping a running `sum` variable and adding to it each time.)

Comment: Or: store the submitted values into an array until the user puts a special line (like f.e. an empty line); then use the array length and sum its values in order to calculate the average.

@iamnotmaynard doesn't want to answer you because you're likely a newbie, and you ___need___ to resolve these problems be yourself

Comment: Also, I would recommend [`String#to_r`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-to_r) (or maybe `to_f`, but probably not) instead of `to_i`. This will allow the user to enter decimals instead of just integers, and will keep you from ending up with truncating errors and things when you divide at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is explained line by line in the comments marked with #

```
def averager
  puts "How many numbers?" #ask the user how many numbers
  numbers = gets.chomp.to_i #get how many numbers
  count = 1 #start the count variable for the while loop
  half_total = 0 #half_total starts on zero
  while(count <= numbers) do #while count is less than or equal to amount of numbers
    puts "Enter #{count}° number" #puts "Enter 1°,2° or whatever number"
    number = gets.chomp.to_i #get the actual number from the user
    half_total = half_total + number #add it to your half total
    count = count + 1 #add one to count so we go to the 2°,3° or wtv number
  end #end the loop

  total = half_total/numbers.to_f #divide half_total by the amount of numbers 
             #.to_f is used to force float division so decimals don't get cut

  puts "The average is: #{total}" #prints the result
  total #returns the result in case you don't want to print it

end #end of the function or method
```

This is made with a simple while loop, like the other answer says check out a tutorial on loops if you are still confused by how they work http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain everything! It worked great

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like:

```
def average(input_str)
  arr = input_str.split
  arr.inject { |sum, x| sum.to_i + x.to_i } / arr.size
end

puts "Please enter numbers you would like to average(separated by a space)"
input = gets.chomp
avg = average(input)
puts "The average is #{avg}"
```

The user will give me a string of numbers like this:

```
Please enter numbers you would like to average(separated by a space)
1 2 3
```

We call a function that takes the string `1 2 3` and puts that into an array with the split call:

```
[1] pry(main)> input_str = "1 2 3"
=> "1 2 3"
[2] pry(main)> input_str.split
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
```

We then can sum up that array using the `inject` method:

```
arr.inject { |sum, x| sum.to_i + x.to_i }
```

Finally we just divide that amongst the size of the total array.

Comment: Has a syntax error on the ')' on line 6 plus even though it works the person who asked the question is clearly a begginner and you are using inject, sum.to_i and giving no explanation whatsoever :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a `while` loop.  [Here's a pretty good guide](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm) on loops in Ruby.

Then at each stage in the loop, ask the user for a number, or to enter something else to quit (for example, quit if they input a string).  Something like this:

```
puts "Enter a number: "
total = 0
count = 0
number = gets.chomp.to_i       # you don't need $stdin here
while number != 0              # calling to_i on a String will return 0
  total += number
  count += 1
  puts "Enter another number, or 'quit' to end: "
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
end

average = total / count
```

This isn't the most graceful way to do it, but probably easier to understand.

Comment: I don't think `number.is_a?(Numeric)` will work. `number` will always be a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Indefinitely Until Break Condition

The easiest way to take an unknown number of arguments is to use [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-loop). This will repeat endlessly, until you trigger an exit from the loop with the *break* keyword or raise [StopIteration](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/StopIteration.html).

The following just collects as many arguments as you want in the *numbers* [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) until you type <kbd>q</kbd> or `quit` followed by <kbd>RETURN</kbd>. It then calculates the average based on the count of items in *numbers* and prints the result to standard output.

```
def avg *args
  args.flatten!
  args.reduce(:+) / args.size
end

numbers = []
loop do
  printf 'Enter number ("q" to quit): '
  input = gets.downcase.chomp
  case input
  when ''
    next
  when /q(uit)?/
    puts avg(numbers)
    break
  else
    numbers << Float(input)
  end
end
```

If you want full readline support or to turn off character echoes to the screen, you can look at a gem like [highline](https://github.com/JEG2/highline) for additional features.

### Sample Output

```
Enter number ("q" to quit): 5
Enter number ("q" to quit): 10
Enter number ("q" to quit): 15
Enter number ("q" to quit): 20
Enter number ("q" to quit): q
12.5
```